# AngularJs get filtered input from ng-repeat to a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working with AngularJs and am filtering an input array with a number of select boxes. On the filtered result, I'm running an ng-repeat to display each element in my now filtered array. Now my question. I want to save the filtered input array as an javascript variable, to later display or print the whole result. I actually only want either the filtered input array saved to a javascript variable or even better, the results of each ng-repeat saved altogether in a variable but updating itself after applying a new filter or a filter again. I'm stuck here. Is there a smooth way to do this. Or do you have a even better idea what would work here? Thank's already. 
Let's say we have a filter for languages and name:

```
<select class="form-control"
              ng-options="l.language for l in languages"
              ng-model="languageModel"
              ></select>
<select class="form-control"
              ng-options="n.name for n in names"
              ng-model="nameModel"
              ></select>


<ul ng-repeat="sq in input| filter:languageModel| filter:nameModel>

<li>Language: {{sq['Language']}}</li>
<li>Name: {{sq['Name']}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want something like :

$scope.var = ... // The filtered result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly store the array in your `ng-repeat`

```
<ul ng-repeat="sq in (filteredInput = (input| filter:languageModel| filter:nameModel))>
```

Now you can access `$scope.filteredInput` to get the filtered array

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I looked for. And so simple. I'm happy now.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the filter directly from javascript:

```
$scope.filteredInput = $filter('languageModel')($scope.input);
```

Where `languageModel` is the name of your filter.
Make sure to inject `$filter` in your controller.

By the way, it is weird to have the `ng-repeat` on the `<ul>` element. Something more appropriate would be to put it on the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sq in input| filter:languageModel| filter:nameModel>
        <span>Language: {{sq['Language']}}</span>
        <span>Name: {{sq['Name']}}</span>
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice thank you I think I can work with that. I will remember that of course I want my code to be appropriate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter function in your code behind, something like this

```
$scope.filterlanguage=function(item){

//add your condition if satisfies return or null
if(condition)
{
return item;
}
return null;


}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that could be a solution that would work for me.